# Caching mouse events during an invoke of showdialog

Tags: c#, wpf, invoke

There are external windows programs that have a button which can call my COM app and it opens a WPF window.   The code below allows my window to open.  The calling window goes inactive, but its still registering clicks.  When my window closes, it starts executing all the cached clicks.  I don't have any control over the applications calling my window.  If I change the dispatcher to BeginInvoke it doesn't deactivate the app window and just opens multiple new instances with each button click.  How can I stop the cached clicks on the deactive window?

```
    public void DoSetupDialog()
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (SetupWindow != null) return;
            SetupWindow = new SetupWindow {Topmost = true};
            SetupWindow.ShowDialog();
            if (ObjectsCount <= 1)
            {
                Close();
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`? You open `SetupWindow` as a modal window with `ShowDialog()` and it should therefore handle all incoming messages/event from the system. Try without `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`. If you want the window to be modeless then call `SetupWindow.Show()` instead.

Comment: The calling thread is from a com interface and gets a calling thread must be STA error.  My main already has a [STAThread].  My thought is that my WPF UI is on a different thread which causes it.

Comment: Can you use `Show` method? Main window will never be deactivate and no issue will occur.

Comment: Changing ShowDialog to Show seems to allow the calling applications to continue and they dispose of their com object which shuts my application down.  The Dialog is meant to hold my window open while the user is finishes. The user closes the dialog and then calling application disconnects.  Kinda an odd setup but it's not my rules.